# Host not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: linux, bash, dns

What the issue is when i run below command it shows host not found error, even there's a reverse entry against that ip.

`host -t txt 142.219.243.136.rf.senderbase.org`

Output:

`Host 142.219.243.136.rf.senderbase.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

The output should be like that `IPAddress.rf.senderbase.org descriptive text "any number"`

`IPAddress = 142.219.243.136`

`any number = it would be any number`

Comment: it works with query instead of rf. `host -t txt 142.219.243.136.query.senderbase.org
142.219.243.136.query.senderbase.org descriptive text "0-0=1|1=SERVER BLOCK|2=7.4|3=7.4|4=1498033|6=0|7=18|8=258935|9=14292|45=N|46=18|48=24|53=DE|54=9.491|55=51.2993"`

Comment: I have another ip which is working with rf. `host -t txt 141.219.243.136.rf.senderbase.org`
Ouput: `141.219.243.136.rf.senderbase.org descriptive text "0.9"`

If we use query instead of rf then shows: `host -t txt 141.219.243.136.query.senderbase.org`
Output: 
`141.219.243.136.query.senderbase.org descriptive text "0-0=1|1=SERVER BLOCK|2=7.4|3=7.4|6=0|7=18|8=258935|9=14297|20=webs01rdns3.DomainName|21=your-server.de|22=Y|23=7.8|24=7.8|25=0|40=3.7|41=4.2|43=3.1|44=89.5|45=N|46=18|48=24|53=DE|54=9.491|55=51.2993"`

How this value **0.9** comes out with using rf ?

Comment: The answer to you post would be that they do not have that record in DNS. So the question is when it gets added to the rf db (just tested with a server IP with the same results, it is in query but not in rf). [Check this post for some additional information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145886/how-to-programmatically-query-senderbase-org)